# Elegant & easy way to user get & post together in form method

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

Which magic I can use to send value name on email, but I need also to show it on example.php, when I cant user get & post together?

html:

```
<form target="_blank" action="email_ok.php" method="post"> 
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="" size="50" required>*povinné - Vaše meno (objednávateľ)<br>
<input type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>
```

example.php

```
<?php
$to = 'xyak@send.com';
$subject = 'FORM';
$message = $_POST['name'];  

mail($to, $subject, $message);
?>

Name is: <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?>
```

After send I received correct email, but Name is: --empty--

Thanks a lot

Comment: In your particular situation, why not just use `$_POST['name']` in both cases?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`$_REQUEST` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), which contains everything `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` contain.